# Android layout issue:unaccounted line displayed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a linear layout with one EditText,two TextView, and a GridView as its child elements.

Following is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


<TextView android:id="@+id/output"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/output_words"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

But when I run the application in a real device,I can also see a line.I don't understand what is causing the line to appear.

[image]

Any input would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

It's the line of `EditText` you've defined in your xml.

Comment: you mean to say EditText has an inherent line ...TextView doesn't have any such line.

Comment: Yes. Try removing the EditText and the line should dissapear.